# HTML5 Video with random speed - autorefresh

Tags: javascript, html5-video

So, I want to play a video as a loop, while random values of `playbackRate` is created to randomly set speed up and down video during another random interval of time.

For that, I have this:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var tempo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 0.5; // TIME TO SET VIDEO SPEED
    var tempo2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 1000; // TIME TO SET INTERVAL TIME


    setInterval(function ()
    {
     document.getElementById("my-video").playbackRate = tempo;
        console.log(tempo , tempo2);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * this.tempo2) + 600);
};
```

For some reason, the video is randomly speed up and down, as I expected, but I need to refresh page to change value.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/syFjy/1/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `tempo` variable in the `setInterval` function

```
setInterval(function ()
{
   document.getElementById("my-video").playbackRate = tempo;
   tempo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 0.5;
   console.log(tempo , tempo2);
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * this.tempo2) + 600);
```

But I think that what you want is also an update of the tempo2 variable, by using a setTimeout call of a function that update the random values, use the tempo2 as new timeout.

```
 var update = function () {
    document.getElementById("my-video").playbackRate = tempo;
    //update random values
    tempo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 0.5;
    tempo2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 1000;
    console.log(tempo, tempo2);
    //recall the method with new tempo2 value
    setTimeout(update, tempo2);
 }
```

See there:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syFjy/4/)

Comment: Too soon, I was exactly doing same thing, only without `tempo2` inside interval time. Thanks! :)